# C# get whole raw XML from ConfigurationManager (not from the config file)

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

As title states, I need to get whole raw XML data from ConfigurationManager but I am unable to find a way to do it.

I tried SectionInformation.GetRawXml(); but I am getting error "This operation does not apply at runtime."

```
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;
var s = section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml();
```

I have a Gupta TD project that uses C# class library to communicate with a web service, and when I try to debug this project my app.config is not used. It works fine when I am executing the program directly, my guess is Gupta TD uses some kind of default configuration <strike>and I am unable to locate it, so reading app.config file is not an option, I need to get it from ConfigurationManager</strike> and thanks to Michael Randall hint I found it using AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile.

Comment: Define "whole raw XML". Your example would only get the XML for one section if it worked.

Comment: well a section would still be better than nothing

Comment: all depends on what you need to do with that xml after you get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just used the [`File.ReadAllText` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
File.ReadAllText("<MyApplicationName.exe>.config")
```

However it does beg the question why you want to do this.

you can use this to get the name of the *ConfigurationFile*

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile
```

[AppDomainSetup.ConfigurationFile Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.configurationfile.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can read the whole config file as xml

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load(Server.MapPath("~/file.config"));
```